# Swift: Make it obvious that a table view is scrollable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Strange question really but here goes.

I have a table view with some custom cells. On larger devices they all fit and it looks great.

However on the smaller devices like iPhone 4 due to the other content on the page the table view shrinks and therefore not all of its cells are in view.

**The problem:**

Without actually physically scrolling the view it would be impossible to tell that there were any other cells.

*Is there a way around this?*

Thanks.

Comment: Make your cells height tall enough such that the last cell fitting the screen would only be half visible, this way the users will know they should scroll.

Comment: Add an opaque image at the bottom of the screen which is overlaying the tableview and creating an impression that some content is hidden and the user needs to scroll the table view.

Comment: It's not a strange question, but it's not really a programming question either. iOS hides the scroll indicators except when the user is actually scrolling (and when momentary told to flash). This makes it hard to discover _any_ scrollable content. It's a problem with iOS in general.

Comment: Alright thanks guys. I have used Nikita's idea to flash the scroll indicators a few times and have also made the cells slightly bigger so on smaller devices you can see 1/2 of the last cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()   
}
```

Comment: Note that is built into UITableViewController. You only need this when adding a table to UIViewController.

Comment: I'm not sure if that works. I added that and I see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate a height for the cells so that the last cell is not visible fully. Seeing a cell cut off half way is a good indication for the user to feel that there is more content beneath.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code:

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200)
```

The first card and the last cart are cut-off which gives an impression that you need to scroll.